# How to have a blog post in Jekyll parse markdown code with ```java instead of {% highlight java %}

Tags: jekyll, markdown

I would like it to parse standard markdown as parsed in github.  I don't like the special syntax of `{% highlight java %}`.

I understand it can parse textile and markdown but I don't get how to change the format of a single blog post to use this syntax with his incompatible with some other systems:

````
```java 
some java code 
```
````

I've noticed that it kind of works, but its syntax highlighting is not as beautiful as with `{% highlight java %}`. I wish it to be the same.

Comment: I think this is working as expected. To tell Jekyll you want the fancier syntax highlighting you have to mark it up properly. Plain old code blocks are fenced with **```** and for fancier [code snippet highlighting with Pygments](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#code-snippet-highlighting) you must use the { highlight <code-type> } markup.